# koush AndroidAsync socket example

Tags: android, socket.io

I am using

https://github.com/Thanhktm/socketio_android

by referring

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

but not sure how to run and test this.

Can any one help to create and test this for socket communication.
If you have any example will be really helpful.

Comment: which socket type?
tcp plain sockets / websockets / socketio?